# Merge PDF Files with References using Ruby

Tags: ruby, pdf, hyperlink, prawn

I have a list of PDF Files which I have to merge into a single PDF file using Ruby. [Combine PDF](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf) was able to do a fine job until now. The issue is that now I have to create an index indicating the pages in which each merged file is located and with links to each page. I was able to do so with [Prawn](http://prawnpdf.org/api-docs/2.0/), however this procedure does not allow me to create references between the index and the pages, even though I can know beforehand in which page each file will start. Prawn has this option, but it does not allow me to insert external PDF files in the process (the template feature was deactivated long ago).

Does anyone have a tool recommendation for merging those pdfs including an index with links?

Comment: Which CombinePDF version did you try? As the author, I know that [version 0.2.24 (link to `Changelog`)](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#change-log-v0234) was updated to include a fix that relates to this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Myst. I'm using the latest one (0.2.34), but I'm still not able do add links. Do you have any link to this topic in the documentation?

Comment: It's undocumented since it isn't user adjustable... the only comment about PDF URLs, links etc' is [in the known limitations sections](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf#known-limitations), which describes how single page "ripping" and "merging" will probably cause links to break.

Comment: But my point is not to create external links. I want to merge a folder of PDFs into a single PDF file and add a TOC containing the name of each merged file and a link to the page where the respective file begins.

Comment: I'm sorry if I weren't clear. I was also referring to internal links between pages, such as when implementing a TOC. All this data is contained in the PDF "Catalog" at the root of the PDF and it will be lost when merging pages (vs. merging whole PDF objects).

Comment: Actually, when I merge my files, the internal links between pages keep intact. The issue is to generate new link between the recently created Index and the first page of each merged file.

Comment: But, I'm assuming, the links created using `prawn` break...? If so, it might be caused by CombinePDF translating the absolute links (page numbers) to references (page objects), as it anticipates structural changes that might move pages around... I think I understand the issue better now... though I'm not sure I can offer a solution just yet.

Comment: Does CombinePDF offer support for creating new absolute links?

Comment: CombinePDF is a hacking tool more than an authoring tool. There isn't an easily supported method for adding links (of any kind), but CombinePDF does converts the PDF into Ruby objects, so technically you can add PDF objects and edit stuff to your heart's content... adding this feature isn't a bad idea. But it's midterms right now at my school and I'm swamped.

Comment: I see. I improvised using prawn outlines, it is not what I wanted, but it will do the jobs, thanks for your attention! =)